# Python Mongoengine - get the first document with a non null value in given attribute

Tags: python, mongoengine

I'm trying to get the first document with a non null value in given attribute. For example, in the db the collection Fruit looks like this:

```
Banana:
  weight: null
  colour: yellow
Apple:
  weight: 100
  colour: green
```

I want my query to return the apple document because its weight a valid value. I tried

```
Fruit.objects.get(weight is not None).first()
```

but when running my query with postman I get the error:

```
Not a query object: True. Did you intend to use key=value?
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the query operator ([doc](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#query-operators)) `__ne` :

```
Fruit.objects.get(weight__ne=None).first()
```